# elasticsearch reindex doesnt use index name specified in script

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried reindexing daily indices from remote cluster and following [reindex-daily-indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-daily-indices) example

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://remote_es:9200"
    }, 
    "index": "telemetry-*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dummy"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless", 
    "source": """
      ctx._index = 'telemetry-' + (ctx._index.substring('telemetry-'.length(), ctx._index.length()));
    """
  }
}
```

It looks like if the new `ctx._index` is exactly the same as the original `ctx._index`, it will use the `dest.index` instead. It reindex all the records into "dummy" index

1. Is this a bug or intended behaviour? I could not find any explanation to this behaviour.
2. Is there a way to reindex (multiple indices) from remote and still preserve the original name?

Answer (score 1):

It's because according to your logic, the destination index name is the same as the source index name. In the documentation you linked at, they are appending `'-1'` at the end of the index name.

In your case, the following logic just sets the same destination index name as the source index name, and reindex doesn't allow that, so it's using the destination index name specified in `dest.index`

```
  ctx._index = 'telemetry-' + (ctx._index.substring('telemetry-'.length(), ctx._index.length()));
```

Also worth noting that this case has been reported [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19662) and [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69819).

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the index name the same as the other cluster. I guess this is a bug then, since there is an open ticket. Do you perhaps know of any workaround?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's [by design](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19662#issuecomment-237533046). The only workarounds I know is to run one reindex per source index or make sure that the target index name is not the same, i.e. just add a small suffix or something

Comment: no. since the script cannot set the index name properly, i had to use shell script to loop through the indices and then reindex one by one